# how to write react correctly 17.0.1 on background image css file?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

here are the 3 options i tried

```
.bg {
    background-image: url("/images/icons/courier.png")
}
```

```
.bg {
    background-image: url("./images/icons/courier.png")
}
```

```
.bg {
    background-image: url("../images/icons/courier.png")
}
```

`icon is located: /public/images/icons/...`
[see here for more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEoe6.png)

gives this error:

**./src/components/header/header.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/components/header/header.css)
Error: Can't resolve '/images/icons/courier.png' in 'E:\New project\yamboo\src\components\header'**

earlier this code -->

```
.bg {
    background-image: url("/images/icons/courier.png")
}
```

worked fine in react version 16.13.1

**help please, I will be grateful !!! thanks in advance!!!**

Comment: Handling image paths is not actually one of React responsibilities, but rather of your build system, the webpack, and the loaders you are using. Do you have set up file-loader?

Comment: no, I did not install the file-loader, my project is on create-react-app

Comment: It should work then, at least according to the documentation https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/

Comment: thanks, but still didn't fix the error (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For time being I have solved the issue by changing the version of "react-scripts" to 3.4.4 in "package.json" file.
More information can be found here -> https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9937

Comment: thank you bro, you helped me wholeheartedly, rollback to the old version can be written on the terminal -> `npm install --latest react-scripts@3.4.4`

Answer (score 1):

```
const divStyle = {
  color: 'blue',
  backgroundImage: 'url(' + imgUrl + ')',
};

function HelloWorldComponent() {
  return <div style={divStyle}>Hello World!</div>;
}
```

The style attribute accepts a JavaScript object with camelCased properties rather than a CSS string. This is consistent with the DOM style JavaScript property, is more efficient, and prevents XSS security holes.

```
import React from "react";
import hcbgImage from "./hcbg.jpg";

function App() {
  return (
      <div
        class="bg_image"
        style={{
          backgroundImage: 'url('+hcbgImage+')',
          backgroundSize: "cover",
          height: "100vh",
          color: "#f5f5f5"
        }}
      >
        <h1>This is Text on top</h1>
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In above example, we import the image and store its path in the variable named hcbgImage. If we console log the variable, we get something like /static/media/hcbg.d1e1f550.jpg. It is the path of the image by React.js.